# Can you create a MS Teams group chat with a /pop via a MS Graph call or any other way that the chat box is popped out of MS teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, groupchat

I am looking to create a groupchat within a C# MS graph call that pops out the windows from MS Teams.  Anyone ever done that before and have a code sample which pops the chat window from the Teams on creation?

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a group chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?msclkid=9e849daebaf911eca0da6e4f5ad39797&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-create-a-group-chat) using Graph API. But there is no API to popout the created group chat.

Comment: Is there any c# code that can pop the group chat?

Comment: It is not possible to do it programmatically.